# Modeling elasticsearch database with denormalization or join fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to elasticsearch, and I'm having a hard time designing the data structure because of my relational database mindset.

Currently, I have a simple elasticsearch 7.4 index, containing multiple establishments with geolocation coordinates assigned to then. Now, I would like to create a structure to hold promotional campaigns that could be tied to multiple establishments, by either using their ids, names, brand_names or keywords. These campaigns will also have start/end dates and could be added or modified frequently. Having all that in ES I could easily locate all nearby establishments with certain active campaigns.

With that in mind, I would like to know which is the best approach to store that information in ES. I could denormalize it and store it together with the establishments but it would be costly to update the entire database each time a campaign is added or changed. Any thoughts?

This is the current establishment index:

```
"keywords": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"brand_name": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"name": {
    "type": "text"
},
"country": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"city": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"street_address": {
    "type": "text"
},
"neighborhood": {
    "type": "text"
},
"region": {
    "type": "text"
},
"postal_code": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"coordinates": {
    "type": "geo_point"
}
```

Comment: Unless u notice performance drop while updating, i would suggest to store the data denormalized and update it when necessary, even if u notice too many updates later, there are ways to manage that, like keeping updates in a buffer and do a bulk update instead of single multiple updates

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal the point is that I will probably have to create a GUI to maintain the campaigns. It will need to list all distinct active campaigns with its respective associations, so the user can add/remove or change them at any time. For this ill need to add a bunch of fields to the same index, or create a inner object with them. It feels a little awkward, but it is the preferred way then?

Comment: unless you aren't using elastic as your primary database, it ain't awkward, elasticsearch is usually added on top of existing relational database to improve performance, its more like pre computing all possible joins to avoid heavy operations at fetch time